# VB.net - 'Property Chars: Is ReadOnly' error in replacing letter of a string

Tags: vb.net

This private sub keeps telling me that 'Property Chars: Is ReadOnly'.

Where have I gone wrong? StrWord is a string, e.g. 'banana'.

What I was hoping it would do is loop through the word, and if the 'guess' (a single letter) matches any letter in the string (StrWord), it would replace it in the corresponding letter in the textbox of the word.

So hangman, more or less.

Thanks and regards,
Cameron.

```
Private Sub Lookup(ByVal Guess)
    Dim Count As Integer = 0
    For Each Character As Char In StrWord
        If Character = Guess Then
            txtResult.Text(Count) = Guess
        Else
            Count += 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

Strings in .NET are immutable.  That means you cannot change them.  Instead, you need to create a new string and assign it to the Text property.  You will find the `System.Text.StringBuilder` class to be helpful as well, as it is mutable, and you can convert it into a String with the the `ToString` method.

Try something like this:

```
Private Sub Lookup(ByVal Guess As Char)

    Dim temp as new StringBuilder(txtResult.Text)

    Dim Count As Integer = 0
    For Each Character As Char In StrWord
        If Character = Guess Then
            temp.Chars(Count) = Character
        Else
            Count += 1
        End If
    Next
    txtResult.Text = temp.ToString()

End Sub
```

or this:

```
Private Sub Lookup(ByVal Guess As Char)

Dim temp as new StringBuilder()

Dim Count As Integer = 0
For Each Character As Char In StrWord
    If Character = Guess Then
        temp.Append(Character)
    Else
        temp.Append("*")
        Count += 1
    End If
Next
txtResult.Text = temp.ToString()
```

End Sub

Answer (score -1):

Do you have the textbox set to ReadOnly to keep the user from modifying it? If so, you may need to change it from ReadOnly to make your change, then change it back to ReadOnly.

You could also try changing it this way:

```
txtResult.Text.Replace(Character, Guess)
```

Comment: This would work perfectly; but sadly the word consists of asterisks (is hidden) until there is a correct guess, then the instances of that character in the word are shown in place of the asterisks. That's why I had to do it with indexes before.

I apologise for not mentioning this before!